# Format time using angular js

Tags: angularjs, select, time, format

I want to fill a select (dropdownlist) with hours from 00 to 23 using angular 
in the format "13:00","08:00" , i tied the following code :

`<option ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(24) track by $index" value="{{$index}}">{{$index | date:'HH:mm'}}</option>`

but the result is "02:00" for all 24 item of the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same calculation in Tomek Sulkowski's answer but use UTC in the date format so the value is independent to the local time zone.

```
<option ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(24) track by $index" value="{{$index}}">
    {{$index * 3600000 | date:'HH:mm' : 'UTC'}}
</option>
```

Comment: how to select a specific item using model ?? <select id="time_hours" ng-model="v.Time">
                                                <option ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(24) track by $index" value="{{$index}}">{{$index>9?$index:"0"+$index}}:00</option>
                                            </select>

Answer (score 2):

Since `$index` is just a series of integers (0, 1, 2, 3 ...) and the filter treats is as a timestamp, what you're increasing here is just milliseconds.

For the hour to change you'd have to increase the number by `3 600 000` milliseconds, so this will do it:

```
<option ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(24) track by $index" value="{{$index}}">
    {{$index * 3600000 | date:'HH:mm'}}
</option>
```

Comment: thanks @TomekSułkowski ,it works but it starts with 02:00 for value 0, 03:00 for value 1, 04:00 for value 4 , ...

Answer (score 0):

Another answer - but simpler :
`<option ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(24) track by $index" value="{{$index}}">{{$index>9?$index:"0"+$index}}:00</option>`